# Perl code - pipe "|" in `open()` statement

Tags: perl, file-io, while-loop, grep, pipe

I have the following code in a Perl .pl file. Do you think there's any issue with this code (I can't understand how it'll work as in the 2nd line there's a "|" character without a command following it)

```
while ( $temp ne "" ) {
        open( PS, "ps -ef | grep deploy.sh | grep ssh | grep -v grep|" );
        $temp = <PS>;
        close(PS);
        print "The Deploy scripts are still running.  Now sleeping 20\n";
        sleep 20;
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, a thriftier way of saying `ps -ef | grep process | grep -v grep` is `ps -ef | grep [p]rocess`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That stray | is a way of Perl of saying that you want the output of that command to be made available to your program. There are several equivalent forms.

Take a look here: [open - perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). Specially at the line that says:

```
open(FOO, "cat -n '$file'|");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
open(my $FOO, "foo");
```

opens the file for reading, while

```
open(my $FOO, "foo |");
```

tell Perl that `foo` is a command to run whose output is to be piped to file handle `$FOO`.

Comment: So, what if I just want to run `foo` without any piped using open?

Comment: @Joel. You can't. You'd use `system`

Comment: OK. Thanks for the information. I'll use `system`.

Answer (score 1):

Since open(FOO, "foo |") just reads from FOO the output of the foo command, each line in the output of the foo command will become a line in the FOO file. The following will be identical to the shell command 'ps -ef':

```
open(PS, 'ps -ef |');
while (<PS>) { print $_ }
```

The command in the 2nd line of your sample is shell pipe filtering the list to produce on the running instances of 'deploy.sh', if the file has a line then there still are instances running, that's why it only reads the first line of input in $temp variable.